# Django enclosing substring in string with anchor tags with href attribute

Tags: python, django, regex, string, jinja2

Right now im using regex to search for the substring in a given string then enclosing it in anchor tags with href that is in jinja template

```
pattern = re.compile(rf"({substring})",re.IGNORECASE);
anchoredString = mark_safe(re.sub(pattern, "<a href=\"{% url 'url' substring %}\">"+substring+"</a>"),string)))
```

The tags work fine but when I click on the link, it tries to redirect me to the literal 
"{% url 'url' substring %}" not the "url" path that I defined in my urls.py.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the url as a string first.  You can do this with the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) method

```
from django.urls import reverse

pattern = re.compile(rf"({substring})",re.IGNORECASE);
# `url` is the name of the url path
url = reverse("url", args=[substring])

anchoredString = mark_safe(re.sub(pattern, f'<a href="{url}">{substring}</a>'),string)))
```